# Prisma Migrating issue with Mongo schema and Enums

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

So I´ve made this schema in first instance

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {

  id        String      @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email     String      @unique
  role      TipoFichaje @default(JORNADA_ENTRADA)
  createdAt DateTime    @db.Date

}

model Entity {

  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name      String
  createdAt DateTime @db.Date

}

enum TipoFichaje {
  JORNADA_ENTRADA
  JORNADA_SALIDA
  DESAYUNO
  COMIDA
  FORMACION
  FORMACION3
}
```

Well then I push the db (prisma db push --preview-feature) and after that I Inserted an object like this:

```
{
  email: "email@gmail.com"
  role:"FORMACION3"
  createdAt:1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
}
```

After that I remove the "Formacion3" ENUM from TipoFichaje and push again (prisma db push)

Like this:

```
enum TipoFichaje {
      JORNADA_ENTRADA
      JORNADA_SALIDA
      DESAYUNO
      COMIDA
      FORMACION
}
```

When I try to get the data with Prisma Studio throws this error:

```
Message: Error in Prisma Client request: 


Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:


  Value 'FORMACION3' not found in enum 'TipoFichaje'
  
Query:
{
  "modelName": "User",
  "operation": "findMany",
  "args": {
    "take": 100,
    "skip": 0,
    "select": {
      "id": true,
      "email": true,
      "role": true,
      "createdAt": true
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: Is it a normal behavior? I mean If i migrate the db with the new changes shouldn't migration fix this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, solution came by Janpio (Head of Engineering @ Prisma)

> [Here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/13425)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).